# Checking Value of array against array inside function C#

Tags: c#, arrays, file-io, console-application, scope

I am new to C# and I am sureI am writing a program that moves files if they meet a certain time criteria due to limitations of an existing 3rd party program. The program works in its current capacity however I want to have it check for files with the same name in the destination and change the name of the file that is being moved, so the program does not error out if there are already existing files with the same name. Also some fname and target are declared in the custom class GloDir and are used in other functions as well.

This works but does not check for files in the target;

```
DirectoryInfo sourceInfo = new DirectoryInfo(GloDir.fname); 
FileInfo[] sourceFiles = sourceInfo.GetFiles("*.zip");                  
//creates array of all files ending in .zip
DirectoryInfo destInfo = new DirectoryInfo(GloDir.target);
FileInfo[] destFiles = destInfo.GetFiles("*.zip");

if (sourceFiles.Length == 0) // check to see if files are present. if not die.
{
    return;
}

foreach (var sFileInfo in sourceFiles)
{
    string sFip = sFileInfo.ToString();                                   
    //file info to string
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sFip);                    
    //get file name
    string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(GloDir.fname, fileName);   
    //Full filename and path
    string targetFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(GloDir.target, fileName);  
    //New Target and Path

    DateTime createdOn = File.GetCreationTime(sourceFile);              
    //get file creation time
    DateTime rightNow = DateTime.Now;                                   
    //Variable for this moment

    var difference = rightNow - createdOn; 
    //Different between now and creation

    var minutos = difference.TotalMinutes;
    //turn difference into minutes

    //If time between creation and now is greater than 120 minutes move file to new directory
    if (minutos >= 1)                                             
    {
        //Console.Write(minutos + "  Old   - Moving! -");               
        //debug console msg
        System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, targetFile);
        //move file to new directory
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1555);
        //debug sleep
    }
}
```

To check for files in the target i changed it to add a If statement that checks the directory for any files then a nested foreach loop that compares the values and that also works. The only issues is when trying to use the string declard within the loop or if statement I copied the code with the addition below. I also left in some of the console writes and sleeps that allow me to watch the program function those will not be in the final code;

```
DirectoryInfo sourceInfo = new DirectoryInfo(GloDir.fname); 
FileInfo[] sourceFiles = sourceInfo.GetFiles("*.zip");
//creates array of all files ending in .zip
DirectoryInfo destInfo = new DirectoryInfo(GloDir.target);
FileInfo[] destFiles = destInfo.GetFiles("*.zip");

if (sourceFiles.Length == 0)
// check to see if files are present. if not die.
{
    //Console.Write("no files present");
    //debug console msg
    return;
}

foreach (var sFileInfo in sourceFiles)
{
    string sFip = sFileInfo.ToString();               
    //file info to string
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sFip);        
    //get file name
    if (destFiles.Length != 0)
    {
        foreach (var dFileInfo in destFiles)
        {
            string dFip = dFileInfo.ToString();  
            //file info to string
            string dfileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dFip);     
            //get file name

            if (dfileName == fileName)
            {
                string newFilename = "Duplicate" + fileName;
                Console.Write(newFilename + "dup change name");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            else
            {
                string newFilename = fileName;
                Console.Write(newFilename + "dest files no duplicate");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
    if (destFiles.Length == 0)
    {
        string newFilename = fileName;
    }
    string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(GloDir.fname, fileName);   
    //Full filename and path
    string targetFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(GloDir.target, newFilename);  
    //New Target and Path

    DateTime createdOn = File.GetCreationTime(sourceFile);
    //get file creation time
    DateTime rightNow = DateTime.Now;           
    //Variable for this moment

    var difference = rightNow - createdOn;
    //Different between now and creation
    var minutos = difference.TotalMinutes;
    //turn difference into minutes

    //If time between creation and now is greater than 120 minutes move file to new directory
    if (minutos >= 1)                                             
    {
        System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, targetFile);
        //move file to new directory
    }
}
```

Every time it stops and says that the newFilename variable does not exist in the current context, even though it should be created based on the conditions of the destination directory. Do i need to delcare the string newFilename differently so that it can be seen outside of the if statement and loop? I am sure this is a simple mistake or one that I have not learned yet. This may also be an issue with variable scope but i would not think so considering the other variable is also a string. Once again I am new to C# and any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Default Sorry, removed the comment...

Comment: h8a can you show the code in the second example you posted in it's full method. it appears that if you want to work against the same destInfo, destFiles, and sourceInfo, then you need to declare that outside of the method scope create the new outside one time if it's going to be referenced in both methods I hope that I am understanding your issue correctly `you may want to look at using the Ref` key word

Comment: @DJKRAZE In the end it will just be the second method. The should turn into the second once it works. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
        if (destFiles.Length == 0)
        {
                string newFilename = fileName;
        }
```

`newFilename` only exists *inside* the if test.

Replace it with:

```
string newFilename = string.Empty;
if (destFiles.Length == 0)
{
    newFilename = fileName;
}
```

Then you'll be able to use it afterwards.

You have done this a number of times in your code.

This MSDN article on [Variable Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) has all the information you'll probably ever need about this topic.

Comment: Good answer, but worth pointing towards the MSDN article on [variable scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) too.

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thank you very much! Now I do have another, it keeps naming the newFilename to filename even though there is a duplicate in the destination. I think this now moves to program flow, but I cannot see why it will not change. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I realized the error that was created was a simple process flow. I gave the sting a value and only changed it if that condition was met rather than trying to change it for all conditions. Thanks everyone.